# How to fix performance problems with nested dictionary with tuples as values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

I've written a program that reads a csv file line by line and does a grouping operation at the same time. This runs fairly well until the dataset reaches a certain threshold where the program starts increasing in time linearly.

The code used to process these files is as follows:

```
import time
data = {}
with open("./[path]/[to]/[file].csv") as f:
    start = time.time()
    i = 0
    f.readline() # Ignore header line
    for l in f:
        _, client, date, amount, io, ca, cat, mt = l.split(',')
        amount = float(amount)
        sumDay, sizeDay, meanDay = data.setdefault(client, {}).setdefault(date, (0, 0, 0))
        data[client][date] = (sumDay + amount, sizeDay + 1, (meanDay * sizeDay + amount) / (sizeDay + 1))
        i += 1
        if i % 500000 == 0:
            print(time.time() - start)
            start = time.time()
```

The csv file structure (with some unnecessary info removed) is as follows:

```
,ClientId,Date,Amount,[...]
0,C5841516,2020-01-01 09:00:00,137.71,[...]
1,C3317977,2020-01-01 09:00:00,136.51,[...]
2,C5107526,2020-01-01 09:00:00,1060.94,[...]
3,C5087842,2020-01-01 09:00:00,130.89,[...]
4,C2938277,2020-01-01 09:00:00,793.64,[...]
5,C9799246,2020-01-01 09:00:00,734.12,[...]
6,C2035898,2020-01-01 09:00:00,107.03,[...]
7,C9310000,2020-01-01 09:00:00,89.17,[...]
8,C4054857,2020-01-01 09:00:00,123.3,[...]
9,C4067165,2020-01-01 09:00:00,846.7,[...]
```

I've printed the time it took to read the last 500k lines from the dataset. These values are described below, together with the client count and amount of lines in the csv.

```
5k clients 3.8m lines | 10.5k clients 16m lines | 11k clients 16.7m lines
0.5572941303253174    | 0.5842881202697754      | 0.7967188358306885
0.5774965286254883    | 0.6746623516082764      | 1.1029884815216064
0.6105935573577881    | 0.6639199256896973      | 1.4002125263214111
0.7133028507232666    | 0.6712498664855957      | 1.883500337600708
0.7059860229492188    | 0.6454544067382812      | 2.0164811611175537
0.6402852535247803    | 0.6314959526062012      | 2.3338706493377686
0.6159951686859131    | 0.6306426525115967      | 2.6350154876708984
0.6128799915313721    | 0.6442699432373047      | 3.265746831893921
0.6154458522796631    | 0.6928198337554932      | 3.409559726715088
0.6257271766662598    | 0.6547060012817383      | 3.964728355407715
0.61846923828125      | 0.6538820266723633      | 4.057897329330444  
0.6247692108154297    | 0.6627013683319092      | 4.411986589431763
0.6428296566009521    | 0.655012845993042       | 4.914895296096802
0.6292152404785156    | 0.6570413112640381      | 6.285972833633423
0.6239409446716309    | 0.6641659736633301      | 5.72735857963562
...                   | ...                     | goes up to 20s
9.5s total            | 20s total               | 265s total
```

A 5% increase in dataset size (10.5k vs 11k clients) makes the time increase linearly over time, while the time stays the same for smaller datasets regardless of the size.

I have found that replacing the tuple that stores the sumDay, sizeDay and meanDay with a list makes the code not increase in time over time. But for smaller datasets this performs much worse. (~0.9s per 500k lines instead of ~0.6s per 500k lines)

What is going on here? Why do tuples stored in a nested dictionary make the code increase in time over time after a certain threshold of keys is reached? And how can this be avoided without using a list instead of a tuple since this affects performance by 50%?

Comment: Disk fragmentation causing larger seek times for larger files or more probably virtual memory thrashing? What if you used `time.process_time()` to measure CPU time instead of elapsed time, what would you see?

Comment: @Booboo even with time.process_time() it increases linearly. Would that mean it's not a memory issue?

Comment: That you see a problem when the values are tuples but not lists strongly suggests that this is a Python issue but now I am doubtful that it's related to memory (I may have sent you on a wild goose chase). If it were a memory issue, I would think you would eventually see the problem for lists at some point, but you say you don't. So I am stumped.

Comment: @Booboo Indeed I don't, even with a dataset 5 times as large (50k clients and over 75m lines of csv) using lists the time does not increase over time. Even though the base speed and memory usage could be lower with tuples.

```>>> sys.getsizeof((0, 0, 0))
64
>>> sys.getsizeof([0, 0, 0])
80```

Answer (score 1):

This is the GC
https://bugs.python.org/issue2607#msg65341
Very very old but sadly true